# container view not showing whole child ViewController

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicontainerview, container-view

I have a view controller, DogViewController, that is supposed to appear inside a Container View. No matter what I do with the auto-layout, the Container View refuses to show the whole DogViewController. The problem does not seem to be the DogViewController. When I move the launching arrow and run the app, the DogViewController scene looks full and fine. But when I move the launching arrow back to the parent of the Container View, then the container view only shows the top portion of DogViewController.

DogViewController has two views in it: a TableView and a TextView. Only the TableView is visible through the container (and that perhaps not even the whole thing). Does anyone have any insight on how to fix this problem?

(I just finished an iOS course and I am trying to build a real app to solidify my skills.) I have already read [the whole of the documentation on auto-layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1) .

Comment: What it the DogViewController? Code sample?

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the exact location in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) where I read it, so let me paraphrase:

*The UITableViewController can only control a single UITableView*.